# How can I synchronize my local repositories with the central one on GitHub?

Tags: git, github

I'm VERY new to the concept of git for managing source code. Before I make the leap, I do have a very basic question.

I understand the concept of cloning etc. But what I'm looking to do is have a central area such as a project on GitHub, where I can store all my code, commit changes etc.

Is there a command in Git to just update an existing clone?

Say I create a new GitHub project, add my code, then run a git clone command on my server to setup a new instance of that. Is there a command in git I can execute which would compare / update as needed? Obviously if there is user content uploaded inside a folder called "images" for example or a license key file uploaded I don't want these overwritten.

I'm hoping git has this function, would make my life super easy if I could just execute a git update command once a day on all the servers.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

There are two commands to "syncronize" your local clone with an upstream repository:

```
$ git push
$ git pull
```

Push sends your changes to the upstream repository. Pull fetches and applies the changes from the upstream repository.

More information about the [Git Distributed Workflow](http://book.git-scm.com/3_distributed_workflows.html).

Comment: When a pull is done, does it remove any files in the path though? Or does it ONLY patch existing files that were modified / create new files?

Comment: `git pull` performs a full merge.  That might include removing files if they have been removed in the remote branch and unchanged in the local branch.

Comment: In that case, is it possible to push or pull from a specific URL (like https://github.com/jarble/nodejs_examples)?

Answer (score 1):

`git pull` first `fetch`es changes from the remote and then `merge`s them to your current branch.